# Error 401 when trying to call appsync from s3 bucket using aws-amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

After setting up *appsync with cognito user pool*, connecting to it using `aws amplify react.js library` from local host, works fine but after uploading it to an s3 bucket, I just receive 401 error :

```
x-amzn-errortype: UnauthorizedException
x-amzn-requestid: eb7e23c8-e02f-4906-831c-2528accc46ae
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

I checked network tab of chrome. in request header there was jwt token .

The wierd thing is when I tried other hostings, they work fine too. so it seems a problem in s3 configuration. Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

My s3 bucket permissions :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "HostingPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-hosting/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

S3 Cors configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <ID>test-users-bucket-cors-rule</ID>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>authorization</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Authorization</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Simplified `react.js` code :

```
const awsmobile ={
    "aws_appsync_region": "...",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://....appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: "...",
        region: "...",
        userPoolId: "...",
        userPoolWebClientId: "...",
    }
};
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
//works fine in localhost but not on s3 bucket !
const users = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUsers));
console.log(JSON.stringify(users.data))
```

Comment: S3 doesn't return 401, I believe some problem with cognito when passing the authorization header and thats where I would look at.

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your schema and the listUsers resolver? It'd help give the whole picture.